# creating a form in html

Tags: html, css, forms

im trying to create a form in html css. this is the form i am trying to replicate [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/mITNz.png

but i cant seem to get it looking like the required format as in the picture above. 
this is my html

```css
*{
        margin: 0;
        padding: 0;
    }
    
    label {
        display: block;
        float: left;
        width: 6em;
    } 
    
    input, textarea {    
        width: 14em;
        display: block;
    }
    
    input[type="radio"] {
        width: 1em;
        margin: .1em .2em;
    }
```

```html
 <!DOCTYPE html >
<html>
  <head>

    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="pracExam2.css">


  </head>

  <body>

    <form action="#" method="get" >
      <label>Given name</label><input type="text" name="givenName" /><br/>
      <label>Family name</label><input type="text" name="familyName" /><br/>
      <label>eMail</label><input type="email" name="eMail" /><br/>
      <label>Address</label><textarea rows="4" name="address"></textarea><br/>
      <label>Service</label>
      <fieldset>
        <label for="service1">Basic</label><input type="radio" name="service" id="service1" value="basic" />
        <label for="service2">Professional</label><input type="radio" name="service" id="service1" value="professional" />
        <label for="service3">Premium</label><input type="radio" name="service" id="service1" value="premium" />
      </fieldset>
    </form>
    <input type="submit" value = "submit form" /><br/>
  </body>

</html>
```

if anybody could help me get this right that would be great

Answer (score 2):

You were *almost* there. Just add a `float: left;` to your `radio inputs`:

[LIVE DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/jbutler483/9uk80fy8/)

```
input[type="radio"] {
    width: 1em;
    margin: .1em .2em;
    float:left;
}
```

There are two 'extra' points to note:

- All ID's should be unique
- Your submit button may be more 'commonly accepted' as being nested within the form, not after it.

With those amendments changed, you should have something similar to [this](http://jsfiddle.net/jbutler483/9uk80fy8/1/)

Answer (score 1):

```css
*{
        margin: 0;
        padding: 0;
    }
    
    label {
        display: block;
        float: left;
        width: 6em;
    } 
    
    input, textarea {       
        width: 14em;
        display: block;
    }
    
    input[type="radio"] {
        width: 1em;
        margin: .1em .2em;
    }
```

```html
 <!DOCTYPE html >
<html>
  <head>

    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="pracExam2.css">


  </head>

  <body>

    <form action="#" method="get" >
      <label>Given name</label><input type="text" name="givenName" /><br/>
      <label>Family name</label><input type="text" name="familyName" /><br/>
      <label>eMail</label><input type="email" name="eMail" /><br/>
      <label>Address</label><textarea rows="4" name="address"></textarea><br/>
      <label>Service</label>
      <fieldset>
        <label for="service1">Basic</label><input type="radio" name="service" id="service1" value="basic" />
        <label for="service2">Professional</label><input type="radio" name="service" id="service1" value="professional" />
        <label for="service3">Premium</label><input type="radio" name="service" id="service1" value="premium" />
      </fieldset>
    </form>
    <input type="submit" value = "submit form" /><br/>
  </body>

</html>
```

Comment: Welcome to SO! Please don't post code-only answers but add a little textual explanation about how and why your approach works and what makes it different from the other answers given. You can find out more at our ["How to write a good answer"](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer) page.

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you try  http://getbootsrtap.com  and i thing this example will help you

http://getbootstrap.com/css/#forms-horizontal

Comment: While this may be useful to the OP, it does not in fact answer their question. Maybe this should be a comment instead?

Answer (score 0):

I've changed the `width` of the `label` inside the `fieldset` and added `float:left` `label` and `input` elements.

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
label {
  display: block;
  float: left;
  width: 6em;
}
input,
textarea {
  width: 14em;
  display: block;
}
input[type="radio"] {
  width: 1em;
  margin: .1em .2em;
}
form {
  border: solid grey;
}
fieldset label,
fieldset input {
  float: left;
}
fieldset label {
  width: auto;
}
```

```html
<form action="#" method="get">
  <label>Given name</label>
  <input type="text" name="givenName" />
  <br/>
  <label>Family name</label>
  <input type="text" name="familyName" />
  <br/>
  <label>eMail</label>
  <input type="email" name="eMail" />
  <br/>
  <label>Address</label>
  <textarea rows="4" name="address"></textarea>
  <br/>
  <label>Service</label>
  <fieldset>
    <label for="service1">Basic</label>
    <input type="radio" name="service" id="service1" value="basic" />
    <label for="service2">Professional</label>
    <input type="radio" name="service" id="service1" value="professional" />
    <label for="service3">Premium</label>
    <input type="radio" name="service" id="service1" value="premium" />
  </fieldset>
</form>
<input type="submit" value="submit form" />
<br/>
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to have block elements

html

```
    <form action="#" method="get" >
    <label>Given name</label><input type="text" name="givenName" /><br/>
    <label>Family name</label><input type="text" name="familyName" /><br/>
    <label>eMail</label><input type="email" name="eMail" /><br/>
    <label>Address</label><textarea rows="4" name="address"></textarea><br/>
    <label>Service</label>
    <fieldset style="display:inline-block;">
        <div class="fieldset_blocks"><label for="service1">Basic<input type="radio" name="service" id="service1" value="basic" /></label></div>
        <div class="fieldset_blocks"><label for="service2">Professional<input type="radio" name="service" id="service1" value="professional" /></label></div>
        <div class="fieldset_blocks"><label for="service3">Premium<input type="radio" name="service" id="service1" value="premium" /></label></div>
    </fieldset>
    </form>
    <input type="submit" value = "submit form" /><br/>
```

css

```
*{
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

label {
    display: block;
    float: left;
    padding:5px 10px;
} 

input, textarea {       
    width: 14em;
    display: block;
}

input[type="radio"] {
    width: 1em;
    margin: .1em .2em;
}

form {
    border: solid grey;
    display:inline-block;
}
.fieldset_blocks{
    display:inline-block;
}
.fieldset_blocks label,.fieldset_blocks input{
    display:inline-block;
}
```

Check this fiddle

http://jsfiddle.net/8kj177et/1/

Comment: @jbutler483 What is the harm

Comment: it stops aligning the input controls

Comment: actually he kept service ids of all 3 services as `service1`

Comment: which *still* doesn't answer the question. making it 'more conventional', yes, but won't fix OP's original question.

Comment: I still don't see any problem in aligning input controls for those radio buttons, he should be writing `input` before `label` if he wants to align them to left which is same in your case too

Comment: It's just that you have also UN-aligned the other inputs, too (family name/eMail inputs now are not level as per OPs example)

Comment: yeah, sorry about that, I just thought he required those radio buttons to be in place

Answer (score 0):

Try this CSS.

It has the proper aligments as per the reference image

```
*{
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 0px;
}

label {
    display: block;
    float: left;
    width: 6em;
  text-align:right;
  margin-right:10px;
} 

input[type="text"], input[type="email"], textarea {       
    width: 80%;
    display: block;
}

input[type="radio"] {
    width: 1em;
    margin: .2em .1em;
  float:left;
}

form {
    border: solid grey;
  padding:10px;
}
```

Check this **[DEMO](http://jsbin.com/xidatarenu/1/edit)**

Answer (score 0):

Try this Out I have add some css and html codes.

```
*{
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
 }

label {
        display: block;
        float: left;
        width: 6em;
    } 

input, textarea 
   {       
     width: 14em;
     display: block;
   }

input[type="radio"] 
   {
        width: 1em;
        margin: .1em .2em;
        float: left;
    }

form 
   {
        border: solid grey;
        width: 350px;
        padding-top: 10px;
        padding-left: 10px;
    }
```

HTML code

```
<html>
    <head>

        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="pracExam2.css">
    </head>

    <body>

        <form action="#" method="get" >
            <label>Given name</label><input type="text" name="givenName" /><br/>
            <label>Family name</label><input type="text" name="familyName" /><br/>
            <label>eMail</label><input type="email" name="eMail" /><br/>
            <label>Address</label><textarea rows="4" name="address"></textarea><br/>
            <label>Service</label>
        <fieldset style="width: 232px;">
            <label style="width:35px" for="service1">Basic</label><input type="radio" name="service" id="service1" value="basic" />
            <label style="width:80px" for="service2">Professional</label><input type="radio" name="service" id="service1" value="professional" />
            <label style="width:60px" for="service3">Premium</label><input type="radio" name="service" id="service1" value="premium" />
        </fieldset>
        <div style="text-align: center;padding-top: 10px;">
            <input type="submit" style="display: inline-block;" value = "submit form" /></div>
        <br/>
        </form>

    </body>

</html>
```